# Adding ID3 Tags in Mutagen by Looping Through a Directory

Tags: python, mutagen

(I'm an absolute beginner in terms of coding, this is my first ever project.)

I'm trying to use Mutagen on Windows 10 to loop through a directory and add ID3 tag track numbers for each of the files encountered. Unfortunately, it seems Mutagen is having trouble recognizing said files. Here is what my code looks like so far:

```
import os
import mutagen
import mutagen.id3
from mutagen.id3 import ID3
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3

files = os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Kurt\Music\Music\Brad Paisley\python test')
count = 0

for file in files:
    path = file
    try:
        tag = EasyID3(path)
    except:
        tag = mutagen.File(path, easy=True)
        tag.add_tags()
    tag['tracknumber'] = count + 1
    tag.save(v2_version=3)
    file.save()
    count = count + 1
```

This is essentially cobbled together from various other things I've googled, but it gives me a massive error when I run it, of which I'll post the first few lines here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kurt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\mutagen\_util.py", line 235, in _openfile
    fileobj = open(filename, "rb+" if writable else "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'americansaturdaynight 01- American Saturday Night - Copy.mp3'
```

As I said, I'm an absolute beginner, so I don't really understand what most of this means, though it seems like it's implying that the directory (or files in the directory?) I've selected doesn't exist, which it very much does. Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with the path - `os.listdir()` only lists the files/directories but not their paths so, unless you happen to be executing your script from the specified path, Python won't be able to find the file.

You can always define your home path as:

```
source_dir = r"C:\Users\Kurt\Music\Music\Brad Paisley\python test"

for name in os.listdir(source_dir):  # iterate over all files/directories in source_dir
    if name[-4:].lower() != ".mp3":  # ignore non-mp3 files
        continue
    path = os.path.join(source_dir, name)  # build the whole file path
    # you can also check with os.path.isfile(path) to make sure it's a file you're processing
    # etc. (your mutagen update logic)
```

You may also want to look into [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) for direct directory list with an applied extension filter pattern so you don't have to do the manual check yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much! The `source_dir` fixed it, though I actually found two more mistakes I was making before I could get it to run: the `'tracknumber'` needed to be a string - so it was `str(count + 1)` - and the `file.save()` part was undefined and unnecessary, as it turned out, so I just removed it.